# can't call a function before dropdown open - onclick not working on aspx page

Tags: asp.net

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="showsDatalistPanel" runat="server" Visible="false" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>

<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dateTimeFilter" CssClass="dateTimeFilterIdentifierCls" runat="server"
         onclick="dateTimeFilter_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Visible="true" ClientIDMode="Static">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <label id="dateTimeFilterLabel" runat="server" style="padding-left: 15px" visible="false">
        בחירת מופע לפי תאריך
    </label>
</div>
```

how can I call server side function on clicking the dropdown? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use click event then you have to simulate it using JS as DropDownList doesn't have build-in onclick functionality:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dateTimeFilter" CssClass="dateTimeFilterIdentifierCls" runat="server"
    onclick="__doPostBack('dateTimeFilter', null);" AutoPostBack="true" Visible="true" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and then in your server code you have modify page load event accordingly:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if(Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET").ToString() == dateTimeFilter.ClientID)
        {
            dateTimeFilter_SelectedIndexChanged(dateTimeFilter, null);
        }
    }       
}
```

But I'm sill confused why you can't just use standard OnSelectedIndexChanged or OnSelectedValueChanged?

Comment: Thank you! OnSelectedValueChanged is not good for me because I need the function to be call when clicking the dropdown not when changing the index. I noticed that the dropdown is inside ```UpdatePanel``` in the question